# How to remove reflection from sunglasses and change the color of lenses in sunglasses

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, google-colaboratory

I am working on a project where I have to remove the reflection on sunglasses and also change the color of lenses. So, I tried to detect the dominant color in the image (sunglass lenses) and then tried to replace that color by another color using OpenCV.

But the code is not working properly. So, Please help me.
Here is the result that have obtained.

Here is the code that I have used to crop part of image(lenses) then detect the dominant color.

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
from skimage.color import rgb2lab, deltaE_cie76
import os

img = cv2.imread('originalimage.jpg')
cropped_lens2 = img[556:2045, 2000:3177]

image = cv2.cvtColor(cropped_lens2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

modified_image = cv2.resize(image, (600, 400), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2_imshow(modified_image)
modified_image = modified_image.reshape(modified_image.shape[0]*modified_image.shape[1], 3)
number_of_colors=2

clf = KMeans(n_clusters = number_of_colors)
labels = clf.fit_predict(modified_image)

counts = Counter(labels)

center_colors = clf.cluster_centers_
ordered_colors = [center_colors[i] for i in counts.keys()]
hex_colors = [RGB2HEX(ordered_colors[i]) for i in counts.keys()]
rgb_colors = [ordered_colors[i] for i in counts.keys()]

plt.figure(figsize = (8, 6))
plt.pie(counts.values(), labels = hex_colors, colors = hex_colors)
```

Input Image and output images are as shown below.

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAjAj.jpg)

[Cropped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9VHW.png)

[color range output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw5X9.png)

Code that I have used to replace range of colors by a single color.
you can also replace it by gradient colors.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("old_Test/DSC-0296 fold.jpg")

img = img.convert("RGB")

datas = img.getdata()

new_image_data = []
for item in datas:
   if item[0] in list(range(0, 80)):
      new_image_data.append((255, 204, 100))
   else:
      new_image_data.append(item)

img.putdata(new_image_data)
img
```

[output image after replacing colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUufL.png)

Comment: Looks like your color range is not sufficient to cover the whole lense area, because the lower part of the lense is brighter. Have you tried to use any image editing software (Paint.Net, GIMP, Photoshop) and try to select the lense area (Magic Wand tool)? That might give you the same problem. So you might need to adjust your threshold, or do some adaptive thresholding to be able to select the correct area.

Comment: My aim is to change only the color of lenses and I have tried to color it by adjusting the color range but not working. either it will color whole sunglass or just part of it.

Answer (score 1):

**Change color of any image using OpenCV:**

*Based on your comment maybe this can help you*

You can make a mask from the part that needs to be changed.

```py
def changeColor(im, msk, hue=130):
    h, s, v = cv2.split(cv2.cvtColor(im.copy(), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV))
    h[np.where(msk == 0)] = hue
    return cv2.cvtColor(cv2.merge([h, s, v]), cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
```

Of these 6 images, the top left is the main image I drew with a graphic software. The image at the bottom left is a mask that tells the algorithm where the image should change. Apart from these 2 images, the other 4 are function tests.

[image]